# Encrypt USB stick and be able to mount it everywhere

Tags: usb, windows, password, veracrypt

I wonder if there's any way to encrypt the data in my USB stick with a password and be able to access to it once I plug the USB on any computer with Windows/Linux.

I've been trying with VeraCrypt but it looks like you need the software installed on every machine you want to mount your USB.

Comment: You want to encrypt it...and make it aviable for anyone when you connect it? That's not really the purpose of encryp, is it?

Comment: I know, but I want it to be easily accessible. If it's not possible I'd like at least to have it password protected as I have some personal files I wouldn't like anyone to see if I lose my USB or something.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

1. Format the USB as you would normally do
2. Encrypt the valuable files with cross-platform encryption software
3. Put the encryption software on the usb stick together with the encrypted files. Now you can decrypt the files everywhere.

For a list of encryption software: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1245367